# Is it possible to implement max_usage_in_bytes for cgroup v2?

Tags: linux

In cgroup v1, we can read memory.max_usage_in_bytes to get the maximum memory usage during program runtime. But I didn't find similar function in cgroup v2.

Can cgroup v2 provide the same function? Or can we only do it by reading memory.current frequently (say every 10ms)?

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution other than polling for `memory.current`?

Comment: @yaqwsx Yes, I ended up using getrusage#ru_maxrss (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) to implement my requirements

Comment: But that uses rlimits, not cgroups if I understand correctly. I would like to get a memory consumption of the whole cgroup (and I have no reliable way of tracking the processes created inside the group).

Comment: Hm, it's so weird it is missing in cgroups v2, our CI workflows are relying on `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.max_usage_in_bytes` to determine max memory consumption at the end of the jobs.. Would be nice if this could be added back

Comment: Just hit this as well, as I look into migrating to cgroups v2 and we relied on the cgroups-based accounting of max_usage_in_bytes

Answer (score 2):

In commit 8e20d4b332660a32e842e20c34cfc3b3456bc6dc (Fri May 13 16:48:57 2022 -0700) in the kernel tree there's the introduction of the memory.peak interface for Cgroup v2.

memory.peak will be the equivalent to memory.max_usage_in_bytes in version 1, and will be exposing the value of memcg->watermark.

This value represents the max memory usage recorded for the cgroup and its descendants since the creation of the cgroup, in non-root cgroups.

```
]$ cat memory.peak 
13356507136
```

It's been backported to RHEL 9.3 in commit 8f095dc4e94f4e.